# Fragment Layount Event Handling

Tags: android, button, android-fragmentactivity, android-transitions

Well I'm facing a problem while I want to go to the activity I've created to display from the Fragment class.

- I've initialized the button correctly.
- Button working good on the Toast.
  PROBLEM :
- Now in my switch case I've applied the intent to go from this frame activity to the one which extends activity. The problem is that. 
  I'm attaching you the photograph what it is saying.
  Thank you in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz571.jpg)

In the image the Main2Activity is the java class which extends the activity. So I want to go in here with the use of the button that is present inside the SecondFragment java class.

Answer (score 0):

You need a context to create an intent. So just use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. One more thing can we replace the layout with a normal layout like fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment_Layout, fragment); so that the navigation drawer remains there and the main layout is been replaced by the any java class not the fragment one.